# How to execute complex queries in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following query that I need to convert to rails like syntax. Is there any way to do it or is it better to just use plain MYSQL for this?

```
SELECT `terminals`.`serial`, Count(*) AS count, MAX(`logs`.`created_at`) AS created_at 
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `terminals` WHERE `terminals`.`user_id`= 1) AS terminals 
INNER JOIN `bap-backend`.`logs` ON terminals.`serial`=`logs`.`serial` 
GROUP BY `serial` ORDER BY `logs`.`created_at`
```

The inner Select is to make sure only terminals of the current_user get selected, then I only need the terminals serial. I need this query to give an overview of all the user his terminals and display how many logs the terminal has provided and when the last log occured. The query works on my test data only the implementation in rails is a bit complicated for me.

Thanks!

### EDIT

For the google people, just use find_by_sql, you can still add variables in it. Just add a class before the command, like following example:

```
@items_event = Item.find_by_sql(["SELECT items.*, ei_relationships.itemprice, ei_relationships.currency, ei_relationships.itemunit
                                      FROM `ei_relationships` INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `ei_relationships`.`item_id`
                                      WHERE `ei_relationships`.`event_id` = ?", @event[:id]])
```

Comment: Always stick with the sql unless you are already sucking in all the data you need anyway, which is a bad idea.

Comment: You mean use your own sql query's? what command should I use?

Comment: No I mean don't pull data off the server to process it, always try and do it in the DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't claim to know anything about rails, so I can't answer that part of the question. But if you do stick with plain MySQL, your query could be cleaned up a little:

```
SELECT
    terminals.serial,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    MAX(logs.created_at) AS created_at 
FROM 
    terminals 
    INNER JOIN `bap-backend`.logs
        ON terminals.serial = logs.serial AND terminals.user_id = 1 /* instead of performing a subquery, just add this to your join conditions */
GROUP BY
    serial
ORDER BY
    logs.created_at
```

This takes out one subquery, which should help your performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes ofcourse adding it in the inner join works like a charm!

Comment: Not the answer but helped me anyways :)